# Get authentication from windows with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory

I'm writing an app for internal use for a company. They don't want to mess around with separate login for the app. They want to be automatically loggedin with their windows login.

Is this possible to do directly from the client? Or do I somehow need to talk to the active directory from the backend (nodejs)?

**UPDATE**

I'm using the MEAN stack. Websever is apache.

Comment: How is the site being hosted? Internally via IIS or on a LAMP stack? Web utilities on windows such as XAMP?

If it is within IIS then check out [IIS Windows Authentication](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication)

I don't have access but there are also methods of setting it via IIS inside of the IIS management console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with pure javascript, check out a library as such:

https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth

If using IIS to host the website, there are some settings within the management console to allow 'Basic Authentication' and 'NT Authentication'.